# how to use CyberGarage sdk share hls stream to xiaomi box in android ？

Tags: android

1. i use api 19 phone,and share screen to xiaomi box3.
2. action is null,and share screen failed.
3. and how to solve it，thanks.

---

**java code:**

- private static final String AVTransport1
  ="urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:AVTransport:1";
- private static final String SetAVTransportURI = "SetAVTransportURI";
- private static final String RenderingControl ="urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:RenderingControl:1";
- private static final String Play = "Play";

  ```
              @Override
              public boolean play(Device device, String path) {
                  Service service = device.getService(AVTransport1);

                  if (service == null) {
                      return false;
                  }
                  final Action action = service.getAction(SetAVTransportURI);
                  if (action == null) {
                      return false;
                  }
                  final Action playAction = service.getAction(Play);
                  if (playAction == null) {
                      return false;
                  }
                  if (TextUtils.isEmpty(path)) {
                      return false;
                  }
                  action.setArgumentValue("InstanceID", 0);
                  action.setArgumentValue("CurrentURI", path);
                  action.setArgumentValue("CurrentURIMetaData", 0);
                  if (!action.postControlAction()) {
                      return false;
                  }
                  playAction.setArgumentValue("InstanceID", 0);
                  playAction.setArgumentValue("Speed", "1");
                  return playAction.postControlAction();
              }
  ```

**error log：**

```
 *03-26 01:58:37.047 5071-7534/com.android.tedcoder.androidvideoplayer I/System.out: CyberGarage warning : java.io.FileNotFoundException: /dev/666ddb97-36e1-6b13-ffff-ffffc7831a22/svc/upnp-org/AVTransport/desc.xml: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    03-26 01:58:37.047 5071-7534/com.android.tedcoder.androidvideoplayer I/System.out: org.cybergarage.xml.ParserException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /dev/666ddb97-36e1-6b13-ffff-ffffc7831a22/svc/upnp-org/AVTransport/desc.xml: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    03-26 01:58:37.047 5071-7534/com.android.tedcoder.androidvideoplayer I/System.out:     at org.cybergarage.xml.Parser.parse(Parser.java:107)
    03-26 01:58:37.047 5071-7534/com.android.tedcoder.androidvideoplayer I/System.out:     at org.cybergarage.upnp.Service.getSCPDNode(Service.java:422)
    03-26 01:58:37.047 5071-7534/com.android.tedcoder.androidvideoplayer I/System.out:     at org.cybergarage.upnp.Service.getSCPDNode(Service.java:471)
    03-26 01:58:37.047 5071-7534/com.android.tedcoder.androidvideoplayer I/System.out:     at org.cybergarage.upnp.Service.getActionList(Service.java:501)
    03-26 01:58:37.047 5071-7534/com.android.tedcoder.androidvideoplayer I/System.out:     at org.cybergarage.upnp.Service.getAction(Service.java:520)
    03-26 01:58:37.047 5071-7534/com.android.tedcoder.androidvideoplayer I/System.out:     at com.android.tedcoder.wkvideoplayer.dlna.engine.MultiPointController.play(MultiPointController.java:41)
    03-26 01:58:37.047 5071-7534/com.android.tedcoder.androidvideoplayer I/System.out:     at com.android.tedcoder.wkvideoplayer.view.SuperVideoPlayer$10.run(SuperVideoPlayer.java:648)
    03-26 01:58:37.047 5071-7534/com.android.tedcoder.androidvideoplayer I/System.out: Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /dev/666ddb97-36e1-6b13-ffff-ffffc7831a22/svc/upnp-org/AVTransport/desc.xml: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    03-26 01:58:37.047 5071-7534/com.android.tedcoder.androidvideoplayer I/System.out:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:409)
    03-26 01:58:37.047 5071-7534/com.android.tedcoder.androidvideoplayer I/System.out:     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
    03-26 01:58:37.047 5071-7534/com.android.tedcoder.androidvideoplayer I/System.out:     at org.cybergarage.xml.Parser.parse(Parser.java:101)
    03-26 01:58:37.047 5071-7534/com.android.tedcoder.androidvideoplayer I/System.out:  ... 6 more
    03-26 01:58:37.047 5071-7534/com.android.tedcoder.androidvideoplayer I/System.out: Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    03-26 01:58:37.047 5071-7534/com.android.tedcoder.androidvideoplayer I/System.out:     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
    03-26 01:58:37.047 5071-7534/com.android.tedcoder.androidvideoplayer I/System.out:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
    03-26 01:58:37.047 5071-7534/com.android.tedcoder.androidvideoplayer I/System.out:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:393)
    03-26 01:58:37.047 5071-7534/com.android.tedcoder.androidvideoplayer I/System.out:  ... 8 more*
```

Comment: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /dev/666ddb97-36e1-6b13-ffff-ffffc7831a22/svc/upnp-org/AVTransport/desc.xml: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)` Please explain what part of this is not making sense to you because the error message is pretty clear - you tried to open a file and it was not found.

Comment: @takendarkk  i think that log means device port is used。 but new problem，dlan is support m3u8 ?